# folderbrowserdialog1 doesn't work in visual studio 2015 enterprise windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried to make a simple application to lock the folder, but after following all the tutorials it didn't work.

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cari_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is in the `folderbrowserdialog1`. This is an error that appears in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015:

> Error CS0103  The name 'folderBrowserDialog1' does not exist in the current context   WindowsFormsApplication2

I have tried to find out for myself on Google and in this forum, but nothing worked.

Comment: "The name 'folderBrowserDialog1' does not exist in the current context" is the best what compiler and anyone else can suggest based on code posted. Please re-read whatever tutorial you've copy-pasted chunks from and see if they define it somehow. So far looks like "typographical error" of missing declaration during copy-paste.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know from the Microsoft website directly to browse folders using "Folderbrowserdialog1"
but it didn't work in my code. website microsoft: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component)

Comment: I suspect they imply you understand that to use control you need to add control to your form... Feel free to provide feedback to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void cari_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = (fbd.SelectedPath);
        }
```

after I tried hard finally the problem was resolved, thank you.
Turns out that c # visual studio can't read folderbrowserdialog1 but FolderBrowserDialog